# Problem with initializing std::<list> or std::<vector>

Tags: c++, std

I've written a class where I use typedef to define a new kind of list and in `private:` I initialize/declare a vector. Neither the list nor the vector appears to be initiated despite the header files for each being included. When I reference either in a different section of code it returns the error `'myList' is not a member of 'myAttribute'`

This is the code I currently have:

in a header file "headerfile.h"

```
namespace MyServiceNamespace
{
    struct {
        double j;
        int c;
    } aStruct;
    
    class ServicesAttributes
    {
     public:
        ServicesAttributes();
        virtual ~ServicesAttributes();
        
        int madeAdd(int a, int b) {return a + b; };
    private:
        int a, b;
    };
}
```

and in MyAttribute file (the one I'm having problems with)

```
#include <headerfile.h>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
namespace myAttribute {
    class myAttributeClass : public MyServiceNamespace::ServicesAttributes {
    public:
        typedef std::list<uint32_t> myList;

        myAttributeClass();
        virtual ~myAttributeClass();
        
        /* functions for the class*/

    private:
        myList theList;
        std::vector<MyServiceNamespace::aStruct> helperStructAttribute;
   }; // class myAttributeClass
} // namespace myAttribute
```

(changed var names because they don't make sense out of context of source)

I've been at a loss because it seems like it's a simple fix but, I've done some research and I haven't been able to find the answer yet. I hope another pair of eyes will help me see the trees from the forest.

I've tried just using an array but it's running into the same problem as the list and vector. I've also tried declaring the list as `typedef std::list<uint32_7>(myList)` but that still returns the error `'myList' is not a member of 'myAttribute'`

When I change the type for the vector to just `int` instead of a struct declared elsewhere, the vector works fine.

**EDIT**
I added better code to support this question (everyone who commented on it was right, I was not careful enough and didn't add enough information).
However: I fixed the problem I was having. The file couldn't find headerfile.h because a problem with the include path. While I would love to know how that caused std::list to not work, I'm probably going to keep this closed to answers. Thanks all for your quick responses and feedback.

Comment: please post a [mcve] and the complete error message

Comment: "'myList' is not a member of 'myAttribute'" suggests that you are doing something wrong in the code you are not showing us. In the code you do show us `myList` is a member of the class `myAttributeClass`

Comment: though you changed the names inconsitently. The class is called `myAttributeClass` but its constructor and destructor have the wrong names. This code will cause other errors

Comment: myattribute is the namespace. mylist is part of the class myattributeclass

Comment: Had to add one more header, but [I can now reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/hEs1qzrGj). Let's get the sucker re-opened

Comment: The crux is in how `aStruct` is defined. You've made a variable named `aStruct` of an anonymous `struct` rather than a `struct` named `astruct`. You want `struct aStruct{...};` rather than `struct {...} aStruct;` in order to use `astruct` as a type. That or you're after something completely different and the question's not as clear as I thought. But most likely a `typedef` was removed and the rest of the definition was not updated to match.

Comment: the code now triggers a compiler error, but not the one you ask about. Nothing in this code would  make a compiler complain about "'myList' is not a member of 'myAttribute'". But if you have code with that error, the error should be clear. `myList` is not a member of `myAttribute` but of `myAttributeClass`

Comment: When you ask your next question keep in mind to provide us the means to help you: (1) What do you expect (be specific, best would be a literal text output). (2) What do you see instead? "Does not work" or even "is not initiated" is not enough. Does it compile? If yes, does it link? If yes, does it run? If yes, what's wrong with its behavior? Be specific. Preferably, provide a session transcript, in text, not a screenshot please. (3) As others remarked: Provide a minimal example which we can plug into our favorite build system, compile and run.

Comment: `aStruct` is a **variable** name, not a **type** name. The type name is anonymous / left out in that case.

Comment: Side note 1: Always prefer `using` over `typedef` in modern C++. (It's easier to read, supports templating etc.) Side note 2: The name of your list type is `::myAttribute::myAttributeClass::myList`. That should work from all contexts that have the appropriate header with declaration included. The type is (indeed!) not directly in the `myAttribute` namespace. You may skip some of the namespace and enclosing class scoping in the type name, depending on context; e.g. it’s just `myList` inside the class. But you can only cut off prefixes from the scope, not a middle segment of it.